# Retrieve custom html attributes in javascript function. No jquery please

Tags: javascript

I have created a button as

```
<button type="button"  name="createTask" id="createTaskNOw" class="createButton" createtype="task" onclick="components.init(this)" >Add Task</button>
```

I also have an external javascript file which have this component.init method where I want to retrieve the custom attribute. So I am doing the following

```
var components = function(){
    var _init = function(attributes){
        console.log("Method Executing:Compnents.init",attributes.createtype);
            }   
    return {
        init:_init,
        }
    }()
```

When I am logging attributes like name or id I can see the expected result but logging createtype is showing undefined. Is there anything wrong in custom attributes.

Comment: That creates invalid HTML. You should be using custom data attributes for this.

Comment: [HTML5 Custom Data Attributes (data-*)](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve attributes with the [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) function.

Here's a working example snippet:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('test');
div.innerHTML = div.getAttribute('data-val'); //returns a string
```

```html
<div id="test" data-val="5"></div>
```

This will place `5` within the `<div>` element.  Working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oy7zw63m/).

Comment: `.getAttribute(...)` will yield the string `"5"` and not the number as `.dataset.val` would do - [HTML5 Custom Data Attributes (data-*)](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Comment: True, but `dataset` has odd compatibility with IE 9 & 10.  It's supported in 11+, though.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, `dataset` is better. But I don't think it converts to a number. [`dataset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-dataset) returns a [`DOMStringMap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#domstringmap), which is a map of [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString)s, which are Strings in JavaScript.

Comment: @Oriol You're right. I've only used it lastly with jQuerys [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) which tries to convert the value to the correct type... - http://jsfiddle.net/6u3ucc6q/

Answer (score 1):

try replacing `attributes.createtype` with `attributes.getAttribute('createtype')` in your function

```
var components = function(){
    var _init = function(attributes){
        console.log("Method Executing:Compnents.init", attributes.getAttribute('createtype'));
            }   
    return {
        init:_init,
        }
    }()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is a bit old school. I recommend you adopt [**`HTMLElement.dataset`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset), which is designed for custom attributes in HTML5.

It looks like:

```
<button type="button" data-createtype="task">Add Task</button>
```

You can get and set the attribute with JS:

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');
console.log(button.dataset.createtype); // task
button.dataset.createtype='announce';
console.log(button.dataset.createtype); // announce
```

As of @jfriend00 mentioned, this feature is only [*partially* supported on IE10 and below](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset). In that case you could shim it with `getAttribute()` like before.

Comment: FYI to the OP.  `dataset` requires IE11.